# Bioutil (Touch ID) shell script in shortcuts.app on MacOS don't work

Tags: applescript, command-line, shortcuts-app, touch-id

I have a problem with `bioutil` function.
In Terminal, I am using two commands which are working:

1. `sudo bioutil -ws -u 0`  # disables TouchID for unlock
2. `sudo bioutil -ws -u 1`  # enables TouchID for unlock

But when I try to make a shortcut in the Shortcut APP on macOS, the commands don't work.
When I insert and start: `#! sudo bioutil -ws -u 0` script is working but nothing happened, Touch ID is still active. What I'm doing wrong?

I have also tried: `#!/bin/zsh sudo bioutil -ws -u 0` and `#! bioutil -ws -u 0`. Still not working.

[image]

Comment: Doesn‘t sudo ask for a password?

Comment: Also, formatting is important, so is the code you put into Shortcuts really just one line or several?

Comment: In terminal yes – sudo, ask for password, but in shortcuts no.

Comment: Only this one line, nothing more

Comment: It probably can‘t ask because there is no way to do so. But can you please add a screenshot of your whole shortcut?

Comment: Photo is added.

Comment: That’s not proper shell syntax (well, it is, but it‘s just a comment). The „run as admin“ takes care of the sudo part, so can you try it with just `bioutil …`?

Comment: Of course, I have tried this option – nothing happens too.

Comment: Please edit the question to add the things you've tried then.

Comment: Why do you add `#!` at the beginning? This turns the whole line into a comment. Just put the command there.

Answer (score 0):

From experience with macOS's Automator rather than Shortcuts, I've had success with this pattern before:

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "sudo /path/to/your/executable"'
```

With sudo configured to use Touch ID, this window pops up:

[image]

Comment: The OPs intent seems to be to enable/disable TouchID, can you clarify how your answer addresses that?